# Cron testing on localhost

Tags: php, cron, localhost

I have created a Cron in php that executes after every 10 minutes.
I want to test weather it will work or not.
How can i test Cron job on localhost?
When I executes cron in browser it works perfectly.

Comment: Why you have down voted?

Comment: Know that localhost isn't equal to Windows.